# customizing each item in windows 8 grid app template

Tags: windows, grid

I would like to customize some of the items in Windows 8 Grid App, unlike the default template  which is the following:

SampleDataItem(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, SampleDataGroup group)

For some dataItems, I would like to add some UI controls such as mediaElement or animations. For others, I don't.

Is there any possible way to deal with such problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a new constructor for Base for use a new custom constructor. Like this:

```
public abstract class SampleDataCommon : PrototypeCeA.Common.BindableBase
{
    private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
//Base constructor

    public SampleDataCommon(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, SolidColorBrush Background)
    {
        this._uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this._title = title;
        this._subtitle = subtitle;
        this._imagePath = imagePath;
        this._background = Background;
    }

    // new customized constructor
    public SampleDataCommon(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, bitmapImage image, String description, String Author)
    {
        this._uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this._title = title;
        this._subtitle = subtitle;
        this._description = description;
        this._image = image;
        this._author = author;
    }
}
```

And now, you need call this new constructor into a new custom class (or existent class) for populate you grid item.

- my english is very very poor, sorry!